# How do you create a gradient of colors for a discrete variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with about 100 ordered categories.  I would like to plot each category as a line separately, with the line colors ranging from a low value (say, blue) to a high value (say, red).

Here's some sample data, and a plot.

```
# Example data: normal CDFs

library(ggplot2)

category <- 1:100
X <- seq(0, 1, by = .1)
df <- data.frame(expand.grid(category, X))
names(df) <- c("category", "X")
df <- within(df, {
  Y <- pnorm(X, mean = category / 100)
  category <- factor(category)
  })

# Plot with ggplot
qplot(data = df, x = X, y = Y, color = category, geom = "line")
```

This produces a pretty rainbow thing (below)[image]

but I'd rather have a gradient from blue to red.  Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The default gradient functions for ggplot expect a continuous scale. The easiest work around is to convert to continuous like @Roland suggested. You can also specify whatever color scale you want with `scale_color_manual`. You can get the list of colors ggplot would have used with

```
cc <- scales::seq_gradient_pal("blue", "red", "Lab")(seq(0,1,length.out=100))
```

This returns 100 colors from blue to red. You can then use them in your plot with

```
qplot(data = df, x = X, y = Y, color = category, geom = "line") +     
    scale_colour_manual(values=cc)
```

[image]

Comment: My gggplot tells me that `Non Lab interpolation is deprecated`, apparently this now only works with a two-color gradient.

Answer (score 16):

Since a discrete legend is useless anyway, you could use a continuous color scale:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = as.integer(category), group = category)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_gradient(name = "category", 
                        low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, but in the real data, I'm working with dates.  I'll see if I can make the continuous legend look sensible with date values.

Comment: Dates are continuous data.

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `scale_colour_gradientn` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = as.integer(category), group = category)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = 'category', colours = c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The viridis scales offer this natively:

```
scale_color_viridis_d()
```